# Make a directory for a category Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to design a new category this category will be separated from the home blog. and this cat has it's own layout and way of design. I've tried category.php, but it didn't work :(

```
    Example:
    wordpress/reviews NOT wordpress/category/reviews
```

Is there any possible way to do it in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check permalink option in yourBlog.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php (it's look not possible to remove /category *)

_* try to write a dot " . " or use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

Answer (score 0):

see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

```
<?php if (is_category('Category A')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category A</p>
<?php elseif (is_category('Category B')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category B</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages, 
I could be left blank</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how I can change the directory from wordpress/category/reviews  to wordpress/reviews ?

Answer (score 0):

you can design different page templates and then apply each template separately to each category, by doing this you can make different designs for each category.